# glew problems (linking, crashing)

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glew

I am trying to set up glew in codeblocks (on Windows). I am linking it statically.
The problem is there are two .lib files `glew32.lib` and `glew32s.lib`. When I link `glew32.lib` I´ve got `undefined reference to ___glewGenBuffers` (or any similar function except `glewInit()`). When I link `glew32s.lib` everything compiles fine but program crashes (segmentation fault) on line with `glewInit()`. Opengl context is created, `#GLEW_STATIC` is defined, glew downloaded from [here](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

My testing program:

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

using namespace std;

void initGL()
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1920,1080);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    initGL();
    glutCreateWindow("TEST");
    GLenum err=glewInit();

    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
    cout<<glewGetErrorString(err)<<endl;
    }

        GLuint foo[2];
        glGenBuffers(2,foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're just looking for someone to make an educated guess / shot in the dark? Why don't you post some actual code? Also where did you get your libs from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `GLEW_STATIC` only if you use the static version of the library `glew32s.lib`.  So if you do, go to compiler settings panel, and to other options add `-DGLEW_STATIC`.

Also make sure you linked the lib correctly by adding `glew32s` to the linker settings.

You also need to link to openGL with `opengl32`.

Comment: Did exactly liek you´ve said still got segmentation fault. 
My linker settings:
glew32s
glew32
opengl32
glu32
freeglut

Comment: Link only the static version of glew. Not both. And the order of linking is important, try : glew32s freeglut glu32 opengl32 (on separate lines).